# How to determine the encoding of the text in a QTextEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, encoding

I am obtaining the content from a `QTextEdit` object by using the following code:

```
QString text=my_QTextEdit.toPlainText();
```

What is the encoding that `QTextEdit` uses, a what encoding is used in the `QString` I get back from the `toPlainText()` call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`QTextEdit.toPlainText()` returns a `QString` object, which is always a **[unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)** character string (see [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qstring.html)).

The `QString` class provides the functions `toLatin1()`, `toAscii()` and `toUtf8()`, which allow you to convert the string from unicode to an 8-bit string that you can process further. So Qt handles the encoding & decoding of the string for you.

If you want to create a QString instance from a given byte-string, you can use the functions `fromAscii()`, `fromLatin1()` or `fromUtf8()`.

Answer (score 1):

All controls in Qt are enabled for 16-bit characters. That means that content of a `QTextEdit` is Unicode (or UTF-32/UCS-4) (see also http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/215203-how-to-correctly-display-Unicodes-in-QPlainTextEdit).
When getting the content of a `QTextEdit` control (via `plainText()`), you get back a `QString` which contains Unicode.
From there on, you can convert to other format as you like: `toUTF8()`, `toUCS4()`, ...